# Get current frame number of video playing with python-vlc

Tags: python, media-player, vlc

I'm trying to make a python program that plays a video in sync with a light show done via Arduino. To achieve this I need to know what frame of the video is currently playing to send out data to the Arduino.

I modified the [cocoavlc.py](https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/master/examples/cocoavlc.py) example of `python-vlc` to play a video, pause, resume and rewind it, go forward and backwards by 10 seconds.

To keep track of the frame number tried the method `get_time` of `python-vlc` but it only updates a few times a second. I had the idea to interpolate its data with a timer but it's not perfect.

Here's the code (without the timer):

```py
import vlc
from pycocoa import __name__ as _pycocoa_

from pycocoa import App, Item, ItemSeparator, MediaWindow, Menu, OpenPanel

from os.path import isfile
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import time

_Movies  = '.m4v', '.mov', '.mp4'
_Select  = 'select a video file from the panel'

class AppVLC(App):
    player    = None
    sized     = None
    Toggle    = None
    video     = None
    window    = None

    def __init__(self, video = None, title = 'AppVLC'):
        super(AppVLC, self).__init__(title = title)
        self.media    = None
        self.Toggle   = Item('Play', self.menuToggle_, key='p')
        self.video    = video
        self.player = vlc.MediaPlayer()

    def appLaunched_(self, app):
        super(AppVLC, self).appLaunched_(app)
        self.window = MediaWindow(title=self.video or self.title)

        if self.player and self.video and isfile(self.video):
            # the VLC player on macOS needs an ObjC NSView
            self.media = self.player.set_mrl(self.video)
            self.player.set_nsobject(self.window.NSview)

            menu = Menu('VLC')
            menu.append(
                Item('Open...', key='o'),
                ItemSeparator(),
                self.Toggle,
                Item('Rewind', key='r'),
                Item('Forward', key='f'),
                ItemSeparator(),
                Item('Back', key='b'))
            ItemSeparator(),
            self.append(menu)

        self.menuPlay_(None)
        self.window.front()

    def menuOpen_(self, item):
        self.menuPause_(item)
        self.badge.label = 'O'
        v = OpenPanel(_Select).pick(_Movies)
        if v:
            self.window.title = self.video = v
            self.player.set_mrl(v)
            self.sized = None

    def menuPause_(self, item, pause = False):
        if pause or self.player.is_playing():
            self.player.pause()
            self.badge.label = 'S'
            self.Toggle.title = 'Play'

    def menuPlay_(self, item_or_None):
        self.player.play()
        self._resizer()
        self.badge.label = 'P'
        self.Toggle.title = 'Pause'

    def menuRewind_(self, item):
        self.player.set_position(0.0)
        self.badge.label = 'R'
        self.sized = None

    def menuForward_(self, item):
        time = self.player.get_time()
        lenght = self.player.get_length()
        time = time + 10000
        if time < lenght:
            self.player.set_time(time)
        self.sized = None

    def menuBack_(self, item):
        time = self.player.get_time()
        lenght = self.player.get_length()
        time = time - 10000
        if time > 0:
            self.player.set_time(time)
        self.sized = None

    def menuToggle_(self, item):
        if self.player.is_playing():
            self.menuPause_(item, pause=True)
        else:
            self.menuPlay_(item)

    def windowClose_(self, window):
        if window is self.window:
            self.terminate()
        super(AppVLC, self).windowClose_(window)

    def windowResize_(self, window):
        if window is self.window:
            self._resizer()
        super(AppVLC, self).windowResize_(window)

    def _resizer(self):
        if self.sized:
            self.window.ratio = self.sized
        else:
            Thread(target=self._sizer).start()

    def _sizer(self, secs=0.1):
        while True:
            w, h = self.player.video_get_size(0)
            if h > 0 and w > 0:
                self.window.ratio = self.sized = w, h
                break
            elif secs > 0.001:
                sleep(secs)
            else:
                break

    def get_frame(self):
        #?


def trackframes():
    frame = 0
    while True:
        if frame != app.get_frame():
            frame = app.get_frame()
            send(frame) #send data to the Arduino

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _video = OpenPanel('Select a video file').pick(_Movies)

    app = AppVLC(video = _video)
    Thread(target = trackframes).start()
    app.run(timeout = None)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only sensible way I have discovered to approximate the frame number in python vlc, is to take the frames per second `player.get_fps()` or 25, if not available and calculate the frame number based on the current playing time.

```
    sec = player.get_time() / 1000
    frame_no = int(round(sec * fps))
```

Comment: This what I tried in the beginning and returns, as you said, only an approximation of the current frame. `player.get_time()` updates only a few times a second and therefore the frame number output looks like `10, 23, 35, 41, 48, 60, 72, 79, 91,...` while I need `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,...` as output. This is because for each frame I have to send specific data to the Arduino with correct timing.

Comment: @AleMonti As far as I am aware, `vlc` cannot be cajoled into providing faster updates. You must either work with what is provided or use a different player that can provide either faster updates or an actual frame number. Given that frame rates per second are often fractions, you will appreciate that getting an accurate value can be difficult.

Comment: I'll try switching to Qt's `QMediaPlayer`, which has the `player.position()` method that looks promising. I've modified their [Player Example](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_multimedia__player.html) which appears to be giving the desiderate output.

Comment: @AleMonti: did you get a working solution out of this? I tried the positionChanged() signal but it is far too slow and does not seem to trigger each frame... Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @fwerre As from my previous reply, I've made the switch to `QMediaPlayer` which works as expected. I don't think there's a way to make it work with VLC as even on the regular windows/mac app the progress bar doesn't move smoothly, meaning that even at the core the position updates are slow.